# What is the etymology of the name Vidura?

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit, etymology, vidura

What is the etymology of the name Vidura? Is there a verse that in the Mahabharata that indicates the meaning of his name and how it arose?

Comment: What's the etymology of covfefe?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Vidura (विदुर), the etymology is derived as *vid-kurac* (lit. “wise” or “intelligent”) using Panini’s rule 3.2.162:

> *vidibhidicchideḥ kurac*
>
> The affix kurac comes in the sense of 'agent having such a habit etc.' after the verbs 1. vid 'to know' 2. bhid 'to divide' 3. chid 'to pierce'.
>
> As viduraḥ paṇḍitaḥ 'a knowing Pandit'; bhiduraṃ kāṣṭam 'a splitting or fragile wood'; chidurā rajjuḥ 'a cutting or breaking rope'. The affix is employed in a reflexive sense after the verbs bhida and chida.
>
> Vart:- The affix kurac comes after the verb vyadha 'to kill'; and there is vocalisation of the semivowel; as vidhuraḥ |
>
> [Source](https://ashtadhyayi.github.io/suutra/3.2/3.2.162/?transliteration_target=iast)

Comment: Is there any verse in the Mahabharata or other text that explains the origin of his name?